# Difference between volatile Task iscompleted and Intelocked

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

The Scope is that the target accessing the methods T1 and T2 should be "gracefully" notified with an exception without the start of operation Delay another time.

What is the difference between the approaches used in methods T1 and T2?
In particular volatile should ensure the latest value if im not wrong,
what is the difference with locking an integer value with `Interlocked.Exchange`?

```
async Task Delay(bool endOperation) {
  try {
    await Task.Delay(2000);
  }
  finally {
    if (endOperation)
      _ = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _lock, 0);
  }
}

volatile Task _t = Task.Completed;
int _lock;
Exception NoConcurrent => new InvalidOperationException("no concurrent");

Task T1() {
  if (!_t.IsCompleted) throw NoConcurrent;
  var t = Delay(false);
  _t = t;
  return t;
}

Task T2() {
  if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _lock, 1) == 1) throw NoConcurrent;
  return Delay(true);
}
```

Comment: What is the usage pattern? Is it possible that the `T1` (or  `T2`) method can be invoked concurrently by two different threads?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between the approaches used in methods T1 and T2? In particular volatile should ensure the latest value if im not wrong, what is the difference with locking an integer value with Interlocked.Exchange?

The problem with `volatile` here is that there is some space between the check and the set:

```
if (something checking _t)
...
_t = ...;
```

Another thread can sneak in there after the check but before the set, and do its own check and set. Then you have two running, each one thinking they're the only one.

`Interlocked` handles this by doing the check *and* set atomically, without the possibility of another thread sneaking in between the two.